# Ensuring that a list of all puppet nodes with certain facts is current

Tags: configuration, puppet

I am using `puppet` to manage about a dozen nodes. One of the servers has a monitoring tool that requires a list of all the nodes and some basic specs.

I want to utilize `puppet` to ensure that the list includes every current node and that the basic specs are current (via the latest `facts` from the node's `facter`).

My first idea was to parse `/var/lib/puppet/yaml/facts` and create the file I need based on that. Not the most elegant idea but it may work.

Anyone have any more elegant suggestions on how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Exported resources](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_exported.html). would make this relatively easy.

It could be as simple as something like this.  But you could use templates or fragments or many other things to generate a file on the system with all the data about all the nodes you want.

Here is a example of something that I use to keep a list of all my nodes and if facter has detected that they are VMs or not.

```
@@file {"/srv/puppet_nodes/hosts.d/$::clientcert":
  content => join( [$::clientcert,
                    "%$::lsbdistid%",
                    "%$::lsbdistcodename%",
                    "%$::virtual%",
                    "\n"],' '),
  tag => 'nodestats',
}

# files will be saved on the filesystem on destnode.example.org
if  $::clientcert == 'destnode.example.org' {
      File <<| tag == 'nodestats' |>>
}
```

Comment: If I understood the documentation correctly, I'd need Puppet DB for exported resources. However, I am using Foreman now and, apparently, [foreman has an alternative](http://blog.theforeman.org/2012/01/getting-foreman-search-results-into.html). Thanks for the tip that lead me to it! And to think I almost didn't ask the question.